# Calculating two fields in a form using JavaScript with a submit button and reset button

Tags: javascript, forms

Here the code that I made and not working looking to see how I would get my sum into the result field, Also looking how to make a reset button to clear all the text from the fields.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/duxubovace/edit?html,output).

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function addition() {
            var x = +document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var y = +document.getElementById('num2').value;
            document.getElementById('result').value = x + y;
            document.result.submit()
        }

        function reset() {}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Calculator Using Forms &amp; JavaScript</h1>
    </header>

    <form>
        Number 1:
        <input type="number" id="num1" value="0" autofocus>
        <br> Number 2:
        <input type="number" id="num2" value="0">
        <br> Result:
        <input type="text" id="result" value="0" readonly>
        <br>
    </form>

    <input type="button" onclick="addition()" value="addition">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To submit form use `.submit()` on `form` and to reset use `.reset()` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mma5jqyk/)

Comment: You are not using jQuery... why did you tag it as such?

Comment: First time posting sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this one?
[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bociganehu/1/edit?html,output)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>
    <script>
        function addition() {
            var x = +document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var y = +document.getElementById('num2').value;
            document.getElementById('result').value = x + y;
            //document.result.submit()

            //if you want use submit, use this code. if only see the result, don't use this
            //Submit is receive data, so you can't see a result.
            //document.getElementById('formId').submit();

            //jquery submit
            //$("form")[0].submit();
        }

        function reset() {
          //no jquery
          document.getElementById('formId').reset();
          //jquery
          //$("form")[0].reset();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Calculator Using Forms &amp; JavaScript</h1>
    </header>
    <form id="formId">
        Number 1:
        <input type="number" id="num1" value="0" autofocus>
        <br> Number 2:
        <input type="number" id="num2" value="0">
        <br> Result:
        <input type="text" id="result" value="0" readonly>
        <br>
    </form>

    <input type="button" onclick="addition()" value="addition">
    <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="reset">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks used this to enhance the original and make one with more calculations [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/finagohuju/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to submit the form?

You can use document.forms. to access the form.

Try this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function addition() {
            var x = +document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var y = +document.getElementById('num2').value;
            document.getElementById('result').value = x + y;
            document.forms.calculator.submit()
        }

        function reset() {
          document.forms.calculator.reset();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Calculator Using Forms &amp; JavaScript</h1>
    </header>

    <form name="calculator">
        Number 1:
        <input type="number" id="num1" value="0" autofocus>
        <br> Number 2:
        <input type="number" id="num2" value="0">
        <br> Result:
        <input type="text" id="result" value="0" readonly>
        <br>
    </form>

    <input type="button" onclick="addition()" value="addition">
    <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="reset">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put the reset into the form and then you don't have to use the click event. Also, the input fields lack the `name` attribute, so they are not going to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

just give an id to the form and in your reset function, just do

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

updates:

according to ROBG's comments, you don't need to bind a function to the button.
you can simply add a

```
<input type="reset">
```

to reset all fields of the form, and if the button is out the form, you can do
    `<input form="formID" type="reset">`
to associate to specific form.

Comment: There is no need for any code to reset the form, a reset button (input type reset) will do that.

Comment: that is brilliant, but what if I want to put the buttons out of the form?that way, the type reset button won't work.

Comment: You can associate a form control that is outside the form using the control's *form* attribute, so `<input form="myForm" type="reset">` can be put anywhere and will reset the form. It works for any control you want to associate with the form, but be careful of accessibility constraints (if they apply).

Comment: that's awesome, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button, so if you want something to happen on submit, attach a listener to the form's submit handler. To reset a form only requires a reset button, no code.

Form controls must have a name to be successful and submit their value with the form, and you can pass a reference to the form using *this* from the listener so you don't need to use *getElementById*.

Implementing the above significantly reduces the amount of code required.

In the following, the submit listener returns false so prevents the form from submitting. If you want the form to submit, just remove the return statement from the in–line listener:

```js
function addition(form) {
  form.result.value = +form.num1.value + +form.num2.value;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator" onsubmit="addition(this); return false;">
  Number 1:
  <input type="number" name="num1" value="0" autofocus>
  <br> Number 2:
  <input type="number" name="num2" value="0">
  <br> Result:
  <input type="text" name="result" value="0" readonly>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

You may not want to submit the form at all, in that case you can make the submit button a plain button and call the function from there, but remember to stop the form submitting otherwise.